# Pansharpen a Landsat TM 4-5 image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, landsat, pansharpening

Is there a way to pansharpen Landsat images that are not sat 7 or 8?  I have an image I am using for a research project that is Landsat TM 4-5 and the resolution is 30m.  Is there a way for me to pansharpen so it is 15m? Or is that only possible with Landsat 7 & 8.

Comment: Have you tried to find the band specifications of the Landsat satellites?

Answer (score 5):

No, Landsat 4 and 5 did not carry a panchromatic sensor with 15m resolution.

Sources:

- https://www.usgs.gov/landsat-missions/landsat-4
- https://earth.esa.int/eogateway/instruments/thematic-mapper-tm-